# Declaring generic methods, clarification needed

Tags: java, generics

Consider the following 2 method declarations:

```
1. public abstract <T extends MetaData> List<T> execute();
2. public abstract List<? extends MetaData>  execute();
```

Both seem to **return back a list of objects that extend MetaData**.

What is the difference between them please?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In the first case you will allow Java to use type inference and infer the type of `T` at each call site.

In the second case you will always get a `List<? extends MetaData>` and so won't be able to assign it to a variable of any narrower type like `List<IntegerMetaData>`.

Comment: Marko, thank you for your response. If `A extends MetaData` why would not `List<A> = execute()` be valid?

Comment: If the return type is `List<? extends MetaData>`, the compiler doesn't know what can stand behind that `?`. For example, it could be `StringMetaData`. It can obviously not allow you to assign it to `List<IntegerMetaData>`. Note that `List<A>` is not a subtype of `List<MetaData>`.

Comment: Oh, i see .. So assignment without cast is not possible and assignment with cast rightfully generates a warning. Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

If there are any subtypes of `MetaData` then the first version can only return an empty list or `null`. The second version may return a list containing instances of `MetaData` and its subtypes.

Example: Say `A` and `B` are subtypes of `MetaData` and `execute` returns a list containing an instance of `A`. The caller might have called execute like so:

```
List<B> list = execute(); // the second version does not allow this
```

The caller said he wanted a list of `B`s, but got a list containing an `A`. Due to type erasure the implementation of `execute` has no way of knowing what the caller asked for. Thus the first version can't be implemented (except to return `null` or an empty list).

Answer (score -1):

In example 1, you cannot must return a List whose generic type is `T`, e.g.:

```
@Override
public <T extends MetaData> List<T> execute() {
    List<T> l = new ArrayList<T>();
    return l; 
}
```

In example 2, you can return a List whose generic type is just `MetaData`, e.g.:

```
@Override
public List<? extends MetaData> execute2() {
    List<MetaData> l = new ArrayList<MetaData>();
    return l;
}
```

What is the difference? In the first case, the *method* has a generic type, `T` and you *must* return something that relates to that type. In the second case, you just return a generic type, but the method itself does not have a generic type.

Comment: How do you figure? There is no mention of `T` in the second case.

Comment: Your class would be defined like this: `public class Demo<T> { ... }`.

Comment: And how would that help? A question mark is a question mark, what does it have to do with `T`?